# Line count discrepancy when using csv

Tags: python

I'm running into a line count discrepancy for a large file I'm trying to process. Specifically, I want to know whether a certain row in a csv file is blank or has a value.

A standard line count -

```
with open('somefile.txt') as filein:
    lines = sum(1 for line in filein)
```

-returns:

```
796330
```

The script to check for the presence of the value -

```
import csv
import sys

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
reader = csv.reader(open('somefile.txt'), delimter='\t')

hasvalue, novalue, i = 0, 0, 0

for row in reader:
    i+=1
    if not row[1]:
        novalue += 1
    else:
        hasvalue +=1

print hasvalue
print novalue
print i
```

-returns a different count for the total number of lines:

```
699512
95406
794918
```

The value in row[1] should be an integer, but an `isdigit()` check returns the same count. Am I running over the system limit?

Comment: Are you sure `somefile.txt` hasn't changed in between these tests? In particular, if one of the tests happened inside the same script that created `somefile.txt`, and you leaked the file the same way you did in your second example, it's quite possible that you were counting its lines before you'd closed and flushed the file, so a whole buffer full of them weren't there yet.

Comment: Meanwhile, there is no "system limit" on the number of lines in a file. There could be a limit on the number of _bytes_ in a file, but even on an ancient system that'll be at least 2 billion, so 800K lines is unlikely to be an issue. And at any rate, if the file were truncated by the system, both methods of reading it would get the same result.

Comment: That's possible. How can I ensure that the file is closed and flushed between tests?

Comment: In the script that generates this file, just call `close` or use a `with` statement (which you should always be doing anyway). Alternatively, wait for the script that generates the file to exit before running any program that tries to read it.

Comment: Using `csv.reader` gives fewer lines and `row[1]` never raises an `IndexError`; does your file have any blank lines?

Comment: A less likely but not impossible problem: This is Python 2.x. If this is also on Windows, you really need to open CSV files in binary mode (with `'rb'`), as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) explain. And you're not doing that. If there are any stray `\r` or `\n` characters that aren't part of a `\r\n`, you will confuse `csv`—usually getting exceptions, but getting lines with the wrong number of columns, overcounting the lines, etc. are plausible. (And if it's Python 2.4 or earlier, you almost never get exceptions, so it's even more plausible.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: What would you expect blank lines to do differently in the two cases?

Comment: Make sure your newline designation is not \r\r\n, which is what happens on Windows when you do not specify the newline argument with `open`. Try `open('somefile.txt', delimiter='\t', newline='')` and read the footnote of http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html

Comment: To get an accurate row count from `csv.reader` you need to explicitly open the file in binary mode with a `mode='rb' argument -- the default when nothing is specified is text mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to be sure, but I'm going to bet it's this:

One of those two methods of counting the lines, you're either (a) doing in the same script that created the file in the first place, or (b) running the counting script while the creating script is still going.

And, given that you leak the file without closing it anywhere in reading:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('somefile.txt'), delimter='\t')
```

I'll bet you do the same thing while writing, maybe:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('somefile.txt', 'w'), delimter='\t')
```

In that case, the file could be sitting around open. Even if the creating code has finished the loop that writes the data and printed "Done writing", the last buffer full of lines could be sitting around in some buffer, rather than written to disk. So, when you then try to read the whole file, you're only reading what's actually there—that is, one buffer worth of lines fewer than you wanted.

Comment: This is what happened. Thanks very much for helping out.